# query sqlite3 2 tables joining them by one column and date period

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database file with the following tables.

```
solicitari-id
           id_im
           data_inchidere
           defect
           tip_solicitare

operatii_aditionale-id
                    id_im
                    data_aditionala
                    descriere
```

First table (solicitari) contains:

```
id , id_im, data_inchidere, defect,tip_solicitare
---------------------------------------------------
1,123456,2017-01-01 10:00:00,faulty mouse,replacement
2,789456,2017-01-01 11:00:00,pos installed,intall
3,147852,2017-01-05 12:00:00, monitor installed,install
4,369852,2017-01-06 11:00:00, monitor installed,install
```

Second table(operatii_aditionale) contain additional operations:

```
id, id_im, data_aditionala, descriere
---------------------------------------------
1,123456,2017-01-02 10:00:00,mouse replaced need cd replacement to
2,123456,2017-01-03 10:00:00,cd replaced system ok
3,123456,2017-01-03 10:00:00,hdd replaced system ok
4,789456,2017-01-04 10:00:00,ac adapter not working anymore
```

What I want to do, is to build a table from these two tables but only with existing data between 2 dates which will look like this:

```
 id_im, data_inchidere, defect,tip_solicitare, id_im, data_aditionala, descriere
 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123456,2017-01-01 10:00:00,faulty mouse,replacement,123456,2017-01-02 10:00:00,mouse replaced need cd replacement to
                                                    123456,2017-01-03 10:00:00,cd replaced system ok
                                                    123456,2017-01-03 10:00:00,hdd replaced system ok
2,789456,2017-01-01 11:00:00,pos installed,intall,789456,2017-01-04 10:00:00,ac adapter not working anymore
3,147852,2017-01-05 12:00:00, monitor installed,install
4,369852,2017-01-06 11:00:00, monitor installed,install
```

I have used `,` as separator here column separator.
I found something similar but is filling the left part for each additional row from second table.

Is there a method to do this directly from sqlite query command or do I need to use a Python script?
By the way, I need this for a Python app.

Thanks

Comment: Dont tag mysql and sql-server next time if you are using sqlite3 server.. i have removed the wrong tags

Comment: What do you mean by "existing data between two dates" ?

Comment: i want to be extracted from database by date, for example: `SELECT im_id,data_inchidere,defect,tip_solicitare FROM solicitari WHERE data_inchidere BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-01-01 23:59:59'; ` . I want the table to contain data only between some dates. thank you